# How to access ci-build-id programmatically in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm wondering if there's any way to access the `ci-build-id` option programmatically in cypress.
This option is set in `cypress run` command when you are recording tests in cypress dashboard.

I understand that oftentimes user would set this himself using a environment variables which can simply be reused.
However, if you are writing a plugin for cypress that should work across several project you don't want to assume which environment variable might be used for it.

The purpose would be, for example, to trigger an event once per cypress test run, which **might** include multiple parallel runs or reruns, thus existing hooks/events won't help on their own, unless I have something like `ci-build-id` that seems like a perfect fit here.

I've looked in cypress `config` and `this` objects inside `cypress.confg.ts` file, but found no reference for it.
Any ideas? Is this value even possible to fetch? Also open to alternative ideas.

Comment: I can see that a value for `ci-build-id` can be passed in on the command line. Are you wanting to access that, a value assigned when it's not passed in?

Comment: No, I want to access it during the test run, after it was assigned (provided I don't know upfront the value or env var that will be used to assign it

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I was asking.